# Import txt file into database need formatting and styling the data

Tags: database, database-design

I am very new to database, I will try my best to explain myself clearly.

I need to import a txt file into my database for my product descriptions, in the file has 4 different languages, but I only need English to be import, and it also require some formatting and styling the data such as to use HTML table, what could be the best way to do this?

Any help will be much appreciate.

Kind regards

Comment: what is the RDBMS (oracle,sql server,mysql,postgresql,sqlite,access,etc)?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Jasmine. :) If you are trying to decide which database type to use, you have to know what works on your computer. It'd help us to know if you're using Windows, a Mac, a Unix box, or something else entirely, as well as if you have a database installed already.

Comment: the website is run on the Linux server and use mysql database with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a manual one off change, and if you have access to MS SQL Server, you can import the file using the built in "Tasks > Import Data.." menu item. You can then delete/modify/add to the rows in the imported table to your heart's content using the built in editor.

Alternatively, if you are using code to input the data, and it's a small file, I'd go with something like this:

```
function IsEnglishRow(row)
    returns whether the row is english or not

function GenerateInsertSQL(row)
    returns "INSERT products (item, ...) VALUES (" + row[1] + ")"

function ImportEverything
    sql = empty string
    allRows = ReadFile.SplitIntoRows
    for each row in allRows
        if IsEnglishRow(row)
            sql += GnerateInsertSQL
    RunSQLOnServer(sql)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, It is very big file has over 7000 products in it, I am planing for it to be run with the cron job and can get update every week, as my supplier regularly add new product to this file.